# Django adding words to image url

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to load an image on my template using:

```
<img src="{{ item.pic }}">
```

It works fine sometimes but once I start doing it from a view it adds the path of that view to my image src automatically causing the image to fail to load.

I want it to be

```
src="images/item.jpg"
```

for example, but because of different views it may end up as

`"view1/images/item.jpg"` or

```
"anotherview/images/item.jpg"
```

causing Django to be unable to find the image. Is there a way to code it so that view names won't be added to the src?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute URL, you can do this with:

```
<img src="/{{ item.pic }}">
```

Normally if this is a `FileField` (or an `ImageField` which is a subclass of a `FileField`), you can let Django determine the URL with:

```
<img src="{{ item.pic.url }}">
```

In that case Django will use the [**`MEDIA_URL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/) and will also serve these files. In production, you will need to configure a webserver like Apache, Nginx, etc.; or let a Content Delivery Network (CDN) serve these files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Adding .url doesn't seem to do the trick though as it still keeps the url from the path in the image url. Also I have "MEDIA_URL = '/media/'" in my settings but there is no "media" in the image url.

Is there a way where I can get the image url to be something like "media/images/item.jpg" regardless of which path I'm going through? Currently the path names are being prefixed to my image url and Django can't find the image.

Comment: @VaultDweller: did you add the media urls to `urls.py`?

Comment: @VaultDweller: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Yeah I did. I didn't do collect staticfiles because I understand it isn't necessary for a local server.

Comment: Wow this is going to sound weird but using the item.pic.url format started working! Just out of curiosity, any idea why it may not have worked at first but then worked later? In any case, thank you for your help!